# Expression Engine Entries Loop in Reverse

Tags: channel-entries

In Expression Engine, how would I go about retrieving the **latest** 3 entries from a channel and then loop through the result set in reverse? I tried something like this to no avail :

{exp:channel:entries channel="news_events" limit="3" orderby="entry_id|date" sort="desc|asc"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to do what you are asking with a single channel:entries.

One way or another you are going to have to make *two* passes through the data. 
Here are some ways:

- exp:query + channel:entries
- php + channel:entries
- channel:entries + embed + channel:entries
- channel:entries + re-sorting in the results on the client side with
  javascript

Here's the a working example of the `channel:entries + embed + channel:entries` method:

**template 1:** (this is the template you call in your browser)

```
{embed="my_template_group/my_embedded_template"
my_entry_ids='
{exp:channel:entries channel="news_events" limit="3" disable="categories|custom_fields|pagination|member_data" backspace="1"}{entry_id}|{/exp:channel:entries}
'}
```

Here we are passing three piped delimited entry_ids as an embed variable to another template called `my_template_group/my_embedded_template`.  Note well the single vs double quotes here.

**template 2** (referenced above as `my_template_group/my_embedded_template`)

```
<ul>
{exp:channel:entries channel="news_events" disable="categories|custom_fields|pagination|member_data" fixed_order="{embed:my_entry_ids}" sort="desc"}<li>{entry_id}:{title}</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Here we have another `channel:entries` call. The key is that we are injecting our entry_ids from the parent template in to the `fixed_order` parameter here and then flipping the sort to `desc`.