# Overriding ORDERBY and SORT on channel:entries and output entries in order given by embedded entry_id list

Tags: channel-entries, entries, orderby, sort, entryid

Is it possible to ignore the `ORDERBY`/`SORT` parameters in an `exp:channel:entry` tag and display the entries as given in a list of IDs?

I have a embedded template where I pass down a list of entry IDs to render out. I would like to output the entries in the order they are passed down as entry_ids. Is this possible?

Here's my current loop:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" entry_id="{embed:ids}" sort="asc"  orderby="status" limit="5"}
```

Where `{embed:ids}` is the list of entries I would like displayed, in the order I would like. I.e. `5|1|3|7`. But there is no parameter which will not re-arrange the output order (by date, author, etc..).

Do I need to use the query module to achieve what I want here? It seems EE will try to arrange by date whenever possible.

For full clarity's sake. This is part of a ChannelForm Newsletter creator that selects events and then submits a list of entries as bar `|` separated entry_is into a input for a given issue. This is then renderd into an email template to be used later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me that [the `fixed_order` parameter](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#fixed-order) is exactly what you are looking for.

Related: [Expression Engine Entries Loop in Reverse](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30587/expression-engine-entries-loop-in-reverse/30600#30600)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fixed_order="{embed:ids}"` parameter.

Documentation can be found [here](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#fixed-order).

Answer (score 0):

<s>Just FYI, if you give the channel:entries tag 'entry_id' parameter, without the order parameters, the output will be in the order specified in entry_id parameter. Just like the fixed_order parameter, which is the correct answer above.</s>
See comments below, my bad, living in the past!

Comment: Actually, no. Then the default order will be applied, which is descending by entry date.

Comment: Hi Low, (excuse the pun!),

Perhaps I'm thinking of older version of EE then (prior to fixed_order parameter) as I've definatly used the entry_id in order trick/hack/thing on older sites! 

Appologies that I mislead, I look at mod.channel.php now (v2.8.1) and can see that yes it will apply entry_date ordering by default now.